# Are Bisq offer ids picked or partially picked by humans?

Tags: decentralized-exchanges, bisq

Two recent Bisq "offer ids" are:

1. "**emzlols**-7639fae0-cd4d-48cf-acc5-abc97dab89db-124"
2. "**aixcp**-6efe1e8d-90bf-4c25-b021-53616cad1109-124"

(Emphasis mine. These are fully public, so I don't see a reason to redact/censor them here.)

I can't help but notice that the first says "**lols**" in it. Is this a pure coincidence, auto-generated randomly, or are these id strings somehow picked by the offer makers/sellers? At least the first part before the first dash?

Comment: isn't that the username of the person that created the offer?

Comment: Hello @bisquit, if you found an answer helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer to your question so others will know too.

Answer (score 1):

Bisq Offer IDs are [randomly generated](https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq/blob/ab35dbcad712eff35f3581e68c63ff43d7c59ff2/core/src/main/java/bisq/core/offer/CreateOfferService.java#L115) and consist of 3 parts separated by "-":

- [Prefix](https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq/blob/a5aea5a0a534e0af253534156300ccb1a0d86de9/common/src/main/java/bisq/common/util/Utilities.java#L404): between 5 to 8 characters in length
- Randomly generated UUID: 5 sections of 4, 2, 2, 2, & 6 hex values separated by "-"
- [Bisq Version](https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq/blob/0cfa7f6702dad86a10086f296599460bb8f4c461/common/src/main/java/bisq/common/app/Version.java#L30): "." separators removed

In your first example, `emzlols-7639fae0-cd4d-48cf-acc5-abc97dab89db-124`, `emzlols` is the Prefix, `7639fae0-cd4d-48cf-acc5-abc97dab89db` is the Randomly generated UUID, and `124` indicates a Bisq Version of 1.2.4

The IDs are created in a method called `getRandomOfferId()` in the `bisq.core.offer.CreateOfferService` class as of Bisq v1.2.4.

The [Short ID](https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq/blob/a5aea5a0a534e0af253534156300ccb1a0d86de9/common/src/main/java/bisq/common/util/Utilities.java#L433) for an offer is its Prefix.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the username?

Comment: Yes, it has nothing to do with the username.